# Accidentally removed "edit" menu in NSMenu, now i need it back

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsmenu

I accidentally removed "edit" menu in the NSMenu of my OS X app.
Now neither Cmd+X nor Cmd+V works.

I did not find a special 'edit' menu in the interface builder's toolbox.

What's the best way to bring back my beloved edit menu?

Comment: 1) Source control, 2) Time Machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to create a new Main Menu template.

Go to File->New->File...

Select OS X -> User Interface -> Main Menu

This will generate a new `MainMenu.xib` for you, which includes your edit menu.
Just copy paste the edit menu view from the new file into your old MainMenu, and you're good